# See git branch containment / parent-child relationships

Tags: git, branch

I have a set of local git branches. I'd like to sort them by "containment".

- If a branch is a parent for another branch, it should be listed before the branch that contains it. All children contain everything that their parent contains.
- Implying: if a branch contains another branch (is a child of that parent), it should be shown after the branch it contains.
- If two branches are independent (they may share a root, but neither strictly contains the other) then that should be clear from the display, perhaps by indenting them together in a group, or something.

I'd love to see a terminal visualisation of that.

Comment: It seems like you're just after `git log --graph`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm afraid there's no built-in way to do *exactly* what you want, but a close free-form approximation would be

```
git log --graph --decorate --oneline --abbrev=commit --all
```

(which is especially nice under the `color.ui` setting set to `auto`).

You might want to specify a list of branches instead of `--all`.

You might still try to script the behaviour you want by exploiting the `--contains` command-line option of the `git branch` command: given a set of branches of interest, you might obtain the list of branches which contain each of those branches, and process the results recursively.  Then sort the outcome appropriately.

Comment: Yeah, that does it – I didn't know how to tell it the branches I wanted! That's very helpful, thanks.

Comment: Is the `x--graph` correct, or should it just be `--graph`?

Comment: This is nice, but kind of useless in my repo that has 20,000 commits. There is no way I can reasonably scroll it and figure out the branching relationships. I know I can do `--decorate --simplify-by-decoration`, but that simplifies too much and removes all the commits where the branches are created. Is there nothing in between?

Comment: @BenFarmer, I suggest you to post a question to the main Git mailing list (post a *non-HTML* message to `git at vger.kernel.org`; see [this](https://subspace.kernel.org/vger.kernel.org.html?highlight=git) for more; [the archives](https://lore.kernel.org/git/)).

Comment: @BenFarmer, while only tangentially related to your Q, I'm inclined to think that your repo might have some workflow/approach problems if you need to put much thought into branch relations. I'd say the most useful question is "does the tip of branch B contain commit C?" ("contain" means can be chased to via child/parent relations), which is easily answerable by `git branch --contains`. The [`git when-merged` tool](https://github.com/mhagger/git-when-merged/) may also occasionally come in handy.

Comment: Yeah I know there are tools to figure out these things one branch at a time. I just wanted to see it nicely in graph form, and it kind of made no sense to me why simplify-by-decoration removes these junctions. Seems too simplified to be useful to me. And well yes there were problems, someone messed up something and polluted the master branch with some junk commits we had to remove, and we needed to investigate where it came from. And yes there are workflow approaches to avoid these issues, but its a small team of mostly scientists and it hasn't been worth setting up better protections etc yet.

Comment: @BenFarmer, I'm afraid there are no such protections built in to Git. Using some "hosting" solution would help (starting from the simplest, like [gitolite](https://gitolite.com/gitolite/index.html), and ending with "turn-key" things like GitLab) as they allow to "protect" a set of branches, and then some policy could be installed meaning that the changes come into these branches only via merges done by a dedicated person (or persons) after having been approved by at least a single reviewer (which might not necessarily be the same set of folks who merges).